# Google Feeds API to display last week feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, google-api

I am using the Google Feeds API to display the last 7 entries. Its working very well. However we have got a new requirement to display only the last week's feeds.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to pass a date parameter and fetch all feeds starting from that date ?

**MY IDEA**

I tried reading the feed api page but didnt see anything of that sort. So my thoughts is I will fetch 100 feeds, store them in an array and then check the date and display them. However this is really not a good solution.

Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try this method:

```
var query = 'daterange:2014-02-10..';
google.feeds.findFeeds(query, findDone);
```

---

### References

[google.feeds.findFeeds(query, callback)](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide?hl=ja#findFeeds) is using search request format for the `query`:

> query supplies the search query for the list of feeds

[Daterange](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1079357) is a request format:

> Restrict search to documents with modification dates that fall within a time frame. You can search any dates between 1900-01-01 and 2079-06-06